# ISY IKE-5000 keyboard only lighting up when connecting to a USB charger port

Tags: linux, usb, laptop, keyboard

Whenever i connect my ISY IKE-5000 keyboard to ANY computer with USB 2.0 or 3.1 ports, the keystrokes work correcly but i can barely see the keys as there are no lights, when there should be. I have used two Windows computers, one Debian computer, and the USB charger i have connected to the mains.

I have tried using `xset led` and `xset led on`, to no avail.

Testing with a USB charger connected to the mains reveals that it does light up whilst connected for a few seconds before turning off.

How can i fix this without replacing the keyboard?

Comment: Do other USB devices work OK on these ports? What's the power requirements for this keyboard? Did it work OK at some point in the past? What changed since it worked?

Comment: Yes, absolutely perfectly, except for the now-returned and refunded LED keyboard, with a less light-depndent keyboard being used now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the keyboard has been returned and so issue can no longer be replicated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the keyboard ties its backlight to the state of the scroll lock led. On sway/wayland, there seems to be no way to turn on the LED properly, but this script exists which you can use to work around the issue: https://github.com/bigrand/scrolllock-wlroots-workaround

To enable this via autostart, I wrote this small shell script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

event=$(cat /proc/bus/input/devices \
            | grep -A99 'Name="SZH usb keyboard"' \
            | grep 'Handlers=' \
            | head -n1 \
            | tr ' ' '\n' \
            | grep -E '^event[0-9]+$')
/path/to/scrolllock-wlroots-workaround/ledToggler.py /dev/input/$event scrolllock scrolllock 1 1 &
```